# Getting Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY error if API returns the empty array Instead of list in kotlin android moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, moshi

Getting error while parsing the API response using Moshi.

Sample Reponses:

Expected API response

```
{"itemsValues":[{"Id":"567"},{"Id":"678"}]}
```

If list is empty it returns the empty array

```
[]
```

API Call:

```
 "Content-Type: application/json"
    )
    @GET("GetID")
    suspend fun getAllId():Response<IdResponse>?
```

Response model:

```
data class IdResponse( @Json(name = "itemsValues") val itemsValues: List<itemsValues>?)
```

while parsing the API response with moshi getting below mentioned error

```
com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $
```

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

> If the list is empty it returns the empty array.

```
[]
```

But in order for your code to work, the response should be:

```
{"itemsValues":[]}
```

Comment: There is any other way to handle without changing the response body ? @Atick faisal

Comment: Just surround the call inside a `try-catch` block. It will throw an exception if the response is an empty list. You can catch that and handle it as fits.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to tell your server team to return consistent response formats, so your other client teams won't run into issues, too, but you can adapt the formats easily with Moshi's JsonReader.

```kotlin
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class ItemsValues(val Id: String)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class IdResponse(val itemsValues: List<ItemsValues>) {
  object Adapter {
    @FromJson fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader, delegate: JsonAdapter<IdResponse>): IdResponse {
      if (reader.peek() == JsonReader.Token.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
        reader.beginArray()
        reader.endArray()
        return IdResponse(emptyList())
      }
      return delegate.fromJson(reader)!!
    }

    @ToJson fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: IdResponse, delegate: JsonAdapter<IdResponse>) {
      if (value.itemsValues.isEmpty()) {
        writer.beginArray()
        writer.endArray()
        return
      }
      delegate.toJson(writer, value)
    }
  }
}

fun main() {
  val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(IdResponse.Adapter).build()
  val idResponseJsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(IdResponse::class.java)
  val encoded = """{"itemsValues":[{"Id":"567"},{"Id":"678"}]}"""
  val emptyEncoded = "[]"
  val decoded = IdResponse(listOf(ItemsValues("567"), ItemsValues("678")))
  val emptyDecoded = IdResponse(emptyList())
  println(idResponseJsonAdapter.fromJson(encoded))
  println(idResponseJsonAdapter.fromJson(emptyEncoded))
  println(idResponseJsonAdapter.toJson(decoded))
  println(idResponseJsonAdapter.toJson(emptyDecoded))
}
```

Prints:

```
IdResponse(itemsValues=[ItemsValues(Id=567), ItemsValues(Id=678)])
IdResponse(itemsValues=[])
{"itemsValues":[{"Id":"567"},{"Id":"678"}]}
[]
```